# Configuration of LDAP client on 12.04

Tags: ldap, client

We have here a way to log in the computers base on Ldap(openldap). You can use any seat with the login/pass you have. Well my problem is that everything worked fine till I had to upgrade Ubuntu to the last version (12.04).

Now, it is far from impossible to log in because you only can choose administrator account! That would be my issue; I want to Lightdm allow me to choose the user e.g : pagonzalez or rmlago or whatever the login-name you have. 
I´ve been searching for 2 days now, and nothing comes up! Hope somebody here has any idea about it!